# What is the most pythonic way to answer this iGCSE CompSci question?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a teacher, not a student, I promise :)

*Exercise: Declare an array.  Use manual input to add integers to array.  If the user enters -1, stop accepting input and do not add -1 to the array.*

Other requirements: this must be as simple as possible, as it is a very early exercise for students who are just starting to program, and must be compatible with iGCSE PseudoCode, which does not allow for breaks/interrupts.

The three versions we are debating at the moment are:

**1. Break**

```
elements = []
while True:
    user_input = int(input("Please enter a whole number. When you want to stop type -1 "))
    if user_input == -1: break
    elements.append(user_input)
```

Argument against: break is not compatible with pseudocode

**2. Repeat Input**

```
elements = []
user_input = int(input("Please enter a whole number. When you want to stop type -1 "))
while user_input != -1:
    elements.append(user_input)
    user_input = int(input("Please enter a whole number. When you want to stop type -1 "))
```

Argument against: repeating the input line is inelegant, and a source of errors when you take this approach on larger programs.

**3. Repeat Condition**

```
elements = []
user_input = 0
while user_input != -1:
    user_input = int(input("Please enter a whole number. When you want to stop type -1 "))
    if user_input != -1:
        elements.append(user_input)
```

Argument against: repeating the condition is inelegant, and this is the longest of the three options

Are there any more elegant solutions that still preserve simplicity?

Comment: I would go with 1.

Comment: Please repeat the intro tour, especially [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  Stack Overflow is not a discussion or homework resource.

Answer (score 1):

My opinion is that using builtin functions is more pythonic:

```py
list(iter(lambda: int(input("Please enter a whole number. When you want to stop type -1 ")), -1))
```

Explanation of `iter(callable, sentinel)`: Returns an iterator which calls `callable` until it returns `sentinel` (In our case `-1`).

`list()` is used to cycle through the iterator and save the elements in a list.

You can also use a function instead of a lambda if you want to do some validation:

```py
def input_number():
    value = input("Please enter a whole number. When you want to stop type -1 ")
    try:
        return int(value)
    except ValueError:
        return -1

x = list(iter(input_number, -1))
```